# Rsquared linear regression for stock market (SP500)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I have programmed a small program to calculate the linear r square of a company through yfinance. This works perfectly

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Para calcular r square
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## To use statsmodels for linear regression
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

## To use sklearn for linear regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


stock='NVCR'
ko_df = yf.download(stock, period="5y", interval="1d", auto_adjust=False, prepost=False)
adj_close_df = yf.download(stock, period="5y", interval="1d", auto_adjust=False, prepost=False)['Adj Close']
adj_close_df_list = list(adj_close_df)


#date_df = yf.download(stock, start1, end1, interval='1d')['Close']
#print(adj_close_df)

length = len(adj_close_df_list)
long_fecha_list = list(range(1, length+1))
#print (long_fecha_list)

#Convertimos nuestras listas en arrays:
adj_close_df_array = np.asarray(adj_close_df_list)
long_fecha_array = np.asarray(long_fecha_list)

print(len(adj_close_df_list))
print(len(long_fecha_list))


correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(long_fecha_array, adj_close_df_array)
correlation_xy = correlation_matrix[0,1]
r_squared = correlation_xy**2

print(r_squared)
```

But I don't achieve the same when I want to read the whole list of S&P500 companies to make the same calculation and show me a list of each company and the value I want to calculate.

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Para calcular r square
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## To use statsmodels for linear regression
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

## To use sklearn for linear regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


# Read and print the stock tickers that make up S&P500
tickers = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]
#print(tickers.head())

# Get the data for this tickers from yahoo finance
data = yf.download(tickers.Symbol.to_list(),period="5y", interval="1d", auto_adjust=True)['Close']
#print(data.head())

# Convertir los datos obtenidos en lista
#data_list = data.to_list()

#adj_close_df = yf.download(stock, period="5y", interval="1d", auto_adjust=False, prepost=False)['Adj Close']
data_list = list(data)

# Calcular la longitud y crear la lista de fechas (importante para calcular la linealidad)
longitud = len(data_list)
long_fecha_list = list(range(1, longitud+1))

#Convertimos nuestras listas en arrays:
data_array = np.asarray(data_list)
long_fecha_array = np.asarray(long_fecha_list)

print(len(data_array))
print(len(long_fecha_list))

#Aqui es donde esta la magia del asunto
correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(long_fecha_array, data_array)
correlation_xy = correlation_matrix[0,1]
r_squared = correlation_xy**2

#Imprimir el resultado
print(tickers, 'tiene una linealidad de:', r_squared) ```
````

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

With some modification to your code to calculate the r-squared :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import yfinance as yf

stock='NVCR'
ko_df = yf.download(stock, period="5y", interval="1d", auto_adjust=False, prepost=False)
adj_close_df = yf.download(stock, period="5y", interval="1d", auto_adjust=False, prepost=False)['Adj Close']
long_fecha_array = np.arange(len(adj_close_df)) + 1
correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(long_fecha_array, adj_close_df)
correlation_xy = correlation_matrix[0,1]
r_squared = correlation_xy**2
print(r_squared)
0.47562817009867037
```

If you try it on multiple tickers, it doesn't work because now your input for `np.corrcoef` is a dataframe with as many tickers for your columns , using an example of just the first 5 entries:

```
tickers = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]
data = yf.download(tickers.Symbol.tolist()[:5],period="5y", interval="1d", auto_adjust=True)['Close']
long_fecha_array = np.arange(len(data)) + 1

data.shape

(1258, 5)
```

We get a data frame of 5 columns. A simple way to do the correlation, and keep track of the names (from which the correlation comes from) :

```
correlation_xy = data.apply(lambda x:np.corrcoef(x,long_fecha_array)[0,1])
r_squared = correlation_xy**2
r_squared

ABBV    0.618443
ABMD    0.028345
ABT     0.921121
AOS     0.215398
MMM     0.180000
```

You can also simply do:

```
(np.corrcoef(data.T,long_fecha_array)[-1,:-1])**2

array([0.61844324, 0.02834468, 0.92112108, 0.21539814, 0.17999961])
```